# sum all rows from databse if particular columns in those rows are the same

Tags: mysql, sum

In my project I need to sum ammount of all rows with the same type and same params, other just leave as they are. For example is i have such a table:

```
id | type | ammount | param1 | param2 | param3
1  |  1   |    5    |   1    |    3   |   2
2  |  1   |    20   |   2    |    3   |   2
3  |  1   |    21   |   1    |    3   |   2
4  |  2   |    10   |   1    |    3   |   2
5  |  2   |    3    |   1    |    2   |   1
```

the result i'd like to achieve is:

```
type | sum of ammount | param1 | param2 | param3
 1   |     26         |    1   |   3    |   2
 1   |     20         |    2   |   3    |   2   
 2   |     10         |    1   |   3    |   2
 2   |     3          |    1   |   2    |   1
```

As you can see rows with id 1 and 3 has summed ammounts because they have same type and all params (param1 and param2 and param3) are identical. How can I achieve this? I use mysql.

Thank you in advance.

Kalreg.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use "group by" clause:

```
use test;

create table Testsum(id int, type int, ammount int,  param1 int, param2 int,  param3 int);

insert Testsum(id, type, ammount, param1, param2, param3) 
values(1, 1,  5, 1, 3, 2),
(2, 1, 20, 2, 3, 2),
(3, 1, 21, 1, 3, 2),
(4, 2, 10, 1, 3, 2),
(5, 2,  3, 1, 2, 1);

/*
id | type | ammount | param1 | param2 | param3
1  |  1   |    5    |   1    |    3   |   2
2  |  1   |    20   |   2    |    3   |   2
3  |  1   |    21   |   1    |    3   |   2
4  |  2   |    10   |   1    |    3   |   2
5  |  2   |    3    |   1    |    2   |   1
*/

select  type, sum(ammount) as ammount, param1, param2, param3
from Testsum
group by  type,  param1, param2, param3;
```

**The result:**

```
type,ammount,param1,param2,param3
1,26,1,3,2
1,20,2,3,2
2,3,1,2,1
2,10,1,3,2
```

Propably the highest ID helps:

```
select  max(id) as id, type, sum(ammount) as ammount, param1, param2, param3
from Testsum
where ammount is not null or ammount <> 0
group by  type,  param1, param2, param3 ;
```

or the lowest id when you specify min(id) instead of max(id).

Comment: thank you, it works. but if i add to select 'id' to see which rows are selected group by show just one (i guess last) id number. is somewhere stored an array with all ids of rows that where grouped by in one?

Comment: So you wanted the sum of id 1 and id 3: which id should the query show? have a look at my edited answer.

Comment: i mean all ids somthing like i can create additional column called ids and it can store all ids that are in this group ie 1,3 in this case

Comment: All ids packed in one field - that is a totaly new question; it's possible.